# What are some tips to keep in mind when solving back of the book exercises?

Tags: learning

I am pretty convinced at this point that the most difficult task when learning in a new topic in physics/mathematics is to actually sit down and do the back of the book problems till you figure out how to do the calculations at least once without mistakes. In my opinion, the experience of actually solving questions can be dreadful at times, so what would be ways to 'ease' /smoothen out the experience?

Tl;dr : Looking for tips on how to approach solving exercises faster

Answer (score 1):

There are probably lots of similar questions on this site and on mathematics SE. Two suggestions.

- Find a friend or group of friends to work on problems with.
- Take a look at Polya's [How to Solve It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It) for problem solving tips.

I think your goal should be learning from problems, not necessarily solving them faster. Good problems ask for more than  calculating correctly and quickly. If that were all there was to problem solving then computers would be better at it than people.